# Stream screen to PC

Tags: android

I'm looking for a solution to stream the android screen to PC. I tried out ashot, androidscreencast, droid@screen but their FPS are too slow (but work all fine). Did someone know another program to cast the screen with a higher rate of FPS?

Comment: You will not find a better alternative than Droid@Screen, can almost guarantee that.

Comment: alright :-) , i try the fps option(Droid@Screen) and i turn on 30fps. But I think their are <10 fps. Is their an other option to get the 30fps?????

Comment: Afaik they all use the capture-screenshot DDMS-function that was never designed to be used for streaming video. Thus only ~10fps. Only decent working option might be to get a device with a hdmi/video output :/

Comment: Are you able to acheive this functionality of screen streaming. If yes how did you manage to the same. Kindly help, i am also looking for same app.